# Specific JSON string value causing problem when going through Datapower mpgw service

Tags: json, ibm-datapower

I have a mpgw Datapower service that takes in a JSON request and passes it to a backend service.

Json request to DP service contains string field that is causing issue.

example JSON request sent to DP:

```
{ "comment" : "example \\r\\n comment" }
```

JSON received by backend service after going through DP:

```
{ "comment" : "example \r\n comment" }
```

As you can see, when the request passes through DP, for some reason it's changing the value of the String by removing a couple backslashes.

I can't find why this is happening or how to solve this issue.  The client sending request to Datapower needs to send the `\\r\\n` as part of the "comment" String.

Answer (score 0):

That's completely valid JSON so it should work.
The quick and dirty way is to set the MPGW to "non-xml" as DataPower is not doing any JSON parsing then.

You need to raise a PMR (=bug report) for it.

Just out of curiosity, does it work with only one backslash?
Does it work with three backslashes?
\r\n or \\\r\\\n I mean... (Edit: the editor takes out three backslashes and replace with two so I had to add five backslashes for it to display three so I hope it looks correct)

Comment: Hi @Anders thanks for the reply.  I have some more detailed info on this.  The request was making it through DP but failing at backend service's request validation, because the String value is getting altered when going through DP.  It's dropping one of the forward slashes in the string.  I updated the post, could you please take another look at the post and see if you have any ideas?

Comment: Can you share some more details on how the service is configured?